# Why is flowable not returning any data if no object is found

Tags: android, android-room

I am using flowable to get data from following the date and it keeps going back to get previous date data now problem with flowable is if a date is not found it stuck not even gives a null error so that I can skip
what can I do here. How to use Single and Maybe?

**DAO**

```
 @Query("SELECT SUM(amount)  FROM Amount WHERE date=:date")
        Flowable<Float> getdateSum(String date);
```

**Datasource**

```
 @Override
        public Flowable<Float> getdateSum(String date) {
            return DAO.getdateSum(date);
        }
```

**Idatasource**

```
  Flowable<Float> getdateSum(String date);
```

**Repository**

```
 @Override
        public Flowable<Float> getdateSum(String date) {
            return mLocalDataSource.getdateSum(date);
        }
```

**Code to get Sum**

```
Disposable disposable1 = Repository.getdateSum(date)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Float>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Float sum) throws Exception {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),sum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {});
```

if the object is not found it should perform Toast or load a layout that object is null

Comment: Why do you have 3 tables based on year? Can't you just keep them all in 1 table and have three different queries? Or just 1 query to get all three?

Comment: it is not clear what exactly of that you want, how shoudl it be sorted, and what exactly is the problem for you to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Single it gives error null if the object is not found here you are using flowable when object is not found it stuck so you won't get error

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(amount)  FROM Amount WHERE date=:date")
        Single<Float> getdateSum(String date);
```

Datasource

```
@Override
        public Single<Float> getdateSum(String date) {
            return DAO.getdateSum(date);
        }
```

Idatasource

```
 Single<Float> getdateSum(String date);
Repository

 @Override
        public Single<Float> getdateSum(String date) {
            return mLocalDataSource.getdateSum(date);
        }
```

Code to get Sum

```
Disposable disposable1 = Repository.getdateSum(date)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<Float>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onSuccess(Float incomesum) {
                                      //on success action
                                   }

                                   @Override
                                   public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                                       if (throwable.getCause() == null) {
                                           //your action if null
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more info. So if I understand you correctly, you want to display a list of items with 3 headers: First year, second year, third year?!
Since your question contains very little information, I will try to explain you how to display header in a recycler view with a made-up example:
Let's say you have an object called 'Product' and a String called 'header'. The string shall act as a header, while the app will display a list of products.

First you need to create two layouts for your two item types. One for the product and one for you header.

I think you are familiar with Recyclerviews and the adapter. We will create a list of the 'Product' and the String in our activity/fragment and declare the list in our adapter class. Like this:

```
var productHeaderList = listOf<Any>()
```

Then we will create two view types:

```
var viewTypeHeader = 0
var viewTypeProduct = 1
```

You probably already have a holder class inside your adapter. You will need two of them. 'HeaderHolder' and 'ProductHolder'. Override the onCreateViewHolder method and call both Headers: Like this:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        viewTypeHeader  -> HeaderHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_header, parent, false))
        viewTypeProduct  -> ProductHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_product, parent, false))
        else -> EmptyHolder(LinearLayout(context))
    }
}
```

You also need to declare the type of your item. Override getItemViewType method, get the current item of your list and assign it to the correct viewType. The method might look like this:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if (productHeaderList.isNotEmpty()) {
        val current = productHeaderList[position]
        when (current) {
            is String -> viewTypeHeader
            is Product -> viewTypeProduct
            else -> viewTypeEmpty
        }
    } else {
        viewTypeEmpty
    }
}
```

Then you simply need to fill your item with data. Go to your onBindViewHolder() method and write data to your text view for example, based on the current holder.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder is ProductHolder) {
        val current = productHeaderList[position] as Product            
        holder.textViewPrice.text = current.price
    } else if (holder is HeaderHolder) {
        //set your header text here
    }
}
```

Hope, I could help you.

Comment: please don;t try to answer untill you are sure you understand the question